# error:hex escape sequence is out of range and write function is reading 12 bytes from a region of 3

Tags: c, unix, terminal

My code which is causing problems:

```
if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\x1b999C\x1b999B", 12) != 12)
        return -1;
```

Here, write() comes from `<unistd.h>`.

So, on compiling it providing two warnings. That hex escape sequence, `"\x1b999C\x1b999B"`  is out of range and ‘write’ reading 12 bytes from a region of size 3.

What I am basically trying to do is move the cursor to the bottom right corner of the terminal window. Why are those warnings there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Octal escapes use one to three (octal) digits only — `"\033999C"` is 5 characters plus a null byte.

Hex escapes use as many hex digits as follow the `\x` sequence.  Therefore, `"\x1b999C"` contains a single hex character constant.

See [§6.4.4.4 Character constants](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4) in the C11 standard for the specification.

There are at least two possible fixes.  One is to encode `\x1B` as `\033` (or `\33` — they're the same, though if the text after the `\x1B` was `777A` instead of `999C`, then the triple-digit octal escape would be necessary.

```
if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\033999C\033999B", 10) != 10)
```

A second is to split the string and use string concatenation:

```
if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\x1B" "999C" "\x1B" "999B", 10) != 10)
```

This works because of what is specified in [§5.1.1.2 Translation phases](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2) — where phase 5 converts escape sequences and phase 6 combines adjacent string literals.

I observe that there are 10 non-null characters in this — if you intended to write the byte 0x01 followed by 5 characters (twice), then 12 makes more sense, and you need to alter where the strings break, of course.

This test code prints `11`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char data[] = "\x1b" "999C" "\x1b" "999B";
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(data));
    return 0;
}
```

Remove the `" "` sequences, and GCC complains:

```
xe43.c: In function ‘main’:
xe43.c:5:19: error: hex escape sequence out of range [-Werror]
     char data[] = "\x1b999C\x1b999B";
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
xe43.c:5:19: error: hex escape sequence out of range [-Werror]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

I compile with the `-Werror` option; otherwise, it would only be a warning.  If compiled without `-Werror` and run, it produces the answer 3, not 11.

Comment: Okay. I am sorry. Would delete this question. I checked the VT100 docs, whose escape sequences I was using. The curson down escape sequence has \x1b[ and then the parameter value and then B. That resolves all my problems. All for just a missing '['

Comment: I'm glad you can't close the question — I think this answer has useful information in it.  Yes, the control sequences for terminals often start `<escape><left-square-bracket>` and you would not have run into the problem, but now you have, I hope, learned some useful information about how C character constants work.

Comment: Yes, this answer has very useful information. Thanks for taking the time out and writing it.